# Ввод в инпут только цифр и знака +

Tags: javascript

У меня для инпута стоит следующее:

```
onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/\D/, '')"
```

как сделать, чтобы помимо цифр можно было ввести ещё и знак + ?

Comment: Вы уверены, что этого достаточно? Если юзер введёт «12+34» — это нормально?

Answer (score 3):

```
onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/[^0-9+]/, '')"
```

Comment: Что бы нельзя было ввести символы, например удерживая клавишу `ттттт`, или через`CTRL+V`.
Нужно добавить модификатор `g` -  `onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/[^0-9+]/g, '')"`

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант.
Недостаток: любые символы можна ввести через `CTRL+V`.

```js
function cislo(){
    if (event.keyCode != 43 && event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57)
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onKeyPress="cislo()">
```

Еще один вариант - символы нельзя ввести даже через `CTRL+V`

```js
document.oninput = function() {
    var input = document.querySelector('.input-0');
    input.value = input.value.replace (/[^\+\d]/g, '');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input-0">
```

Comment: Вроде ТС спрашивает цифры и +. Мне удалось ввести: `123 /&*-+"!`.

Comment: Исправил ошибку.

Comment: полная замена значения в обработчике не очень хорошая затея

Comment: @Grundy - а какая затея хорошая? Извините за любопытство..

Comment: просто показать ошибку.

Comment: Тоже вариант. Все зависит от задачи. Но тогда придется вручную, тому кто вводит исправлять уже написанное. А так даже опечатка не пройдет, или кучу текста вставляете из буфера, а остается только телефон.